# Failed to authorize with Pusher - Flutter

Tags: flutter, pusher

I am trying to connect to a private channel that is developed by Pusher with Laravel Back-End, I have used the pusher_channels_flutter package, but the problem is the package has a poor explanation of how to connect with private channels, I have connected with public channels before using this package but failed to connect with it when it is private, I have tried different solutions provided by GitHub and here, the last pusher config set up I made was this :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:chat_test/services/local_data.dart';
import 'package:pusher_channels_flutter/pusher_channels_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PusherConfig {
  PusherChannelsFlutter pusher = PusherChannelsFlutter.getInstance();

  pusherget(int id , Function(dynamic e) oncontrollerevent  , Function(dynamic e) oneevent) async {
    // print(Shared.getstring("token"));
    await pusher.init(
        apiKey: "2.....7",
        cluster: "us2",
        onConnectionStateChange: onConnectionStateChange,
        onSubscriptionError: onSubscriptionError,
        onSubscriptionSucceeded: onSubscriptionSucceeded,
        onEvent: oncontrollerevent,
        onAuthorizer: onAuthorizer
       ); 
       
    await pusher.subscribe(channelName: 'private-chat.${int.parse(Shared.getstring("id")!)}', onEvent: oneevent);
    await pusher.connect();
  } 
     dynamic onAuthorizer(
      String channelName, String socketId, dynamic options) async {
    String token =  Shared.getstring("token")!;
    var authUrl = "http://192.168.1.102:8000//broadcasting/auth";
    var result = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(authUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
      },
      body: 'socket_id=$socketId&channel_name=$channelName',
    );
    var json = jsonDecode(result.body);
    return json;
  }


  void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
    print("onEvent: ${event.data}");
  }

  void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName, dynamic data) {
    print("onSubscriptionSucceeded: $channelName data: $data");
  }

  void onSubscriptionError(String message, dynamic e) {
    print("onSubscriptionError: $message Exception: $e");
  }

  void onMemberRemoved(String channelName, PusherMember member) {
    print("onMemberRemoved: $channelName member: $member");
  }

  void onConnectionStateChange(
      dynamic currentState, dynamic previousState) async {
    print("Connection: $currentState");
    if (currentState == "CONNECTED") {
      var s = await pusher.getSocketId();
      print(s);
    }
  }

  // void onPusherEvent(dynamic event) {
  //   // Handle the received event here
  //   print("Received event: ${event.data}");
  //   // Add your event handling logic here
  // }
}
```

The OnAuthorizer is the method to authorize with the Pusher, and the error that is returning from Pusher is this : Pusher authorize error: error
I/flutter (29115): onSubscriptionError: Didn't receive all the fields expected from the ChannelAuthorizer, expected an auth and shared_secret. Exception: com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: Didn't receive all the fields expected from the ChannelAuthorizer, expected an auth and shared_secret.

i could not understand what should i do or what are the auth and shared_secret that i should send and how to ? , is the shared_secret is the secret_key itself or it's different

Any Solutions on how to solve the issue ?